# how to build sparcline diagram using only one value with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, diagram

how to build a diagram with d3.js  using only "y" values?

```
 var dataOne = [
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 597
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 298
    },
    {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 325
    },
    {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 876
    },]
```

now i`m building my sparcline with "x" and "y" using this code:

```
function displayGraphExampleOne(elemId,
                            width,
                            height,
                            circle_radius,
                            interpolation,
                            data,
                            last_element) {

var graph = d3.select(elemId).append("svg:svg")
                             .attr('width', '100%')
                             .attr('height', '100%')
                             .append('g')
                             .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 2)');


var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height - 4, 0 ]);


var line = d3.svg.line().x(function (d) { return x(d.x); })
                        .y(function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                        .interpolate(interpolation);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.y; }));


graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data))
                        .attr('id', 'linePath');
var sparkPoint = last_element;


graph.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
        .attr('cx', x(sparkPoint.x))
        .attr('cy', y(sparkPoint.y))
        .attr('r', circle_radius);
```

}

Do i need only to remove all occurencies of "x" and use only real values without indexes?

Comment: What do you want the line to look like?  If you only use x you'll get a flat line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the index of the value in the array as your x position, you can do it by specifying the index as a second parameter to all the relevant functions:

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function (d, i) { return x(i); })
                        .y(function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                        .interpolate(interpolation);

x.domain([0, data.length]);
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.y; }));


graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data))
                        .attr('id', 'linePath');
var sparkPoint = last_element;


graph.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'sparkcircle')
        .attr('cx', x(data.length)) //I'm assuming, since sparkPoint=last_element
        .attr('cy', y(sparkPoint.y))
        .attr('r', circle_radius);
```

If you don't have any other properties of the data, you could just use an array of numbers for your data, by changing the y-functions to use `d` instead of `d.y`.

Comment: this x.domain(0, data.length), doesn`t work , this too x(data.length), i have else such thing : 
var x = d3.scale.linear().range(x_range);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range(y_range);

Comment: Ooops, sorry -- I've corrected the code.  The max and min for domain and range methods have to be a two-element *array*, not two separate parameters, so it should be `x.domain([0, data.length])`.